# Going to specific URL using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use React Router to go to a specific page on my app that displays a user's information.
All of my React routes are stored within a separate file and exported like:

```
export const USERS = "/users/:userId";
```

What I want to be able to do is call this route, which I can import into my app. However, I want to be able to specify the specific `userId` to go to. Any help with this would be appreciated.

I import my routes using `import * as ROUTES from "../../constants/routes";`. Then can call `ROUTES.USERS` to access this specific route. I just need to be able to pass the `userId` object.

I have a page set up that will be able to get the `userId` from the route parameters, and subsequently, load the user's information.

Current react dependencies in package.json:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
```

**EDIT**

Adding some more detail about my question...
So what I have is a table, with rows of users in them. When I click a user I want to view a page with those details. I can get the `userId` from the table row correctly, but my question is about how do I put this `userId` into the router.
Currently, I have a variable stored for the URL I want to go to (`export const USERS = "/users/:userId")`. Then in my JS I have as follows:

```
props.history.push(ROUTES.USERS);
```

I'm wanting to know how to amend the `userId` variable into this constant (if it's possible). I'm aware of the way to get it out of the URL when on the user-specific page. I think I can just do `props.history.push('users/${userId}')` but I ideally don't want to have to do that if possible. Thanks again!

Comment: What I think you are trying to do just needs you to add the userId to the end of the link, if using Link, then :  <Link to={'/page you wanna go to /' + userId} /> then on the linked page, to grab the id:  ownProps.match.params.userId;

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply Mark. It's not quite the answer I am looking for. I'll detail more above. I can see what you mean though, but ideally I just want to be able to pass this userId into the `ROUTES.USERS` constant if possible.

Comment: Have you tried?
props.history.push(`${window.location.pathname}/${userId}`)

Comment: Hey @codingwithmanny thanks for that. I am a little bit apprehensive on using `window.location` as we have always been taught to not use it. Especially since this is a React application, it doesn't seem proper to me. I may be wrong however. I am able to get it working hardcoding in using: ```props.history.push(`users/${userId}`)```    but it isn't my ideal solution.

Comment: If you want the base information it would probably be the way to go. With react router, if you console.log the props.match, you'll see that this data isn't there, but that may be on purpose if you plan on using `window.location.pathname`. Unless there is a specific use-case that prevents you from using it, it's probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Revised this based on clarification.

Answer should be;

```
props.history.push(`${window.location.pathname}/${userId}`);
```

If you `console.log(props.match)`;

You get the following data from **React Router**:

```
{
  "path": "/users/:id",
  "url": "/users/7",
  "isExact": true,
  "params": {
    "id": "7"
  }
}
```

You could technically do a str replace for the end, but that would not be ideal if the id is longer or changes.

In most cases, `window.location.pathname` would be the way to go.